# Netty: Disabling auto-read doesn't work for `ByteToMessageDecoder`?

Tags: java, netty

I am using 4.1.0.Final from Maven central.

In my application, I disable auto-read after a certain point like this:

`channel.config().setIsAutoRead(false);`

I do not make any calls to `read`, yet my application still reads. In my pipeline there is only one `ByteToMessageDecoder`, and my (sharable) initializer is my server bootstrap's child handler.

Why is this? Can auto-read not be disabled on-the-fly? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you have a ByteToMessageDecoder in your pipeline it will continue to read until you put an Object into the out List of the decode method. This is because otherwise the user may never have the chance to call read() by himself.

Answer (score 4):

[FlowControlHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/flow/FlowControlHandler.java) was recently added and may be useful in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem, solved it by setting `ByteToMessageDecoder#singleDecode` to true.